# jQuery handle JS form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    //DO STUFF HERE             
});
```

But, it's not detecting/catching/handling the submit that's happening in this JavaScript

```
document.form1.submit()
```

Seems super straightforward.  I'm sure it's something simple/stupid on my part.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's "jQuery", not JQUERY, Jquery or JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery only catches default browser behaviour, like a click on a submit button, and events that were added by jQuery itself...

Answer (score 0):

Calling the submit method of a form with JavaScript will bypass any event handlers attached to the form. They fire when the user submits the form, not when the page does.

You need to trigger any event handlers manually when you submit programatically. The [jQuery submit method](http://jsfiddle.net/VACws/1/) will abstract this away for you. So call `submit()` on a jQuery object instead of directly on an HTMLFormElementNode.

```
jQuery('#form1').submit(); // Assuming you have a form with an id instead of the obsolete name attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest submitting the form with jQuery as well - replace your `document.form1.submit()` with:

```
$('#form1').submit();
```

This works around a number of browser inconsistencies regarding which actions trigger which javascript events.

Answer (score -1):

Specify an id on your form element and then use that id like

```
$("#formid").submit(function() {
    //DO STUFF HERE             
});
```

Comment: That will just bind the handler to a single form instead of all forms, it won't solve the problem.

Comment: how about applying it on every form using its class

$(".formclass").submit(function() {
    //DO STUFF HERE             
});

Comment: — Changing the forms that the event handler is bound to, or the method used to select the forms that it is bound to, will not cause event handlers to be fired when the submit method is called programatically.